# Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'. > Couldn't delete stale output file

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I am trying to run this command in the `android` folder

```
gradlew bundleRelease
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
>
> > Couldn't delete stale output file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appearenltly the build folder was in use by adb.exe, I force quitted it and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to clean the `gradle` and re-run the command.

1. Navigate to the `android` directory `cd android`
2. Clean `gradle` `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply deleted the file whose path was mentioned in the error.